# How can a diode parallel to the source can't take the source value but take about 0.7V?

Tags: diodes

I was practicing diode circuits and this question stucked in my mind. When a diode connected parallel to a DC voltage source, doesn't it have to take the value of the source rather than 0.7V according to Kirchoff laws ? ( the diode is forward-biased )

Comment: Could you please inform us how the diode is poled in the circuit you have in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an ideal circuit with a ideal voltage source with a perfectly constant voltage output and no output resistance, and ideal diode with no resistance and a constant voltage drop, there is no answer. It is a contradiction, which is why it is ideal and doesn't actually exist. It is basically unstoppable force (the voltage source) versus immovable object (the diode voltage drop). In general, this is why ideal things are ideal. They are simple to work with, but there's a logical contradiction lurking in there somewhere that doesn't allow it to actually exist.

But in reality:

- the voltage source has output resistance which causes the voltage
  output to decrease as the current supplied increases
- the diode's voltage does change very slightly as current increases
  as the current running through it increases

This means that as the current increases the source voltage output and the diode voltage drop approach each other. However, good voltage sources have low output resistance, and diodes take a lot of current to change their forward voltage drop by a little bit  so the practical result is usually that the voltage source has to output so much current that it explodes before the equilibrium can be reached.

Comment: I think i got it, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a simplified diode formula.  Google "Shockley diode equation".  In that, you'll find this: $$I = I_{ss}\left( e^\frac{V_D}{n V_T} - 1\right)$$

So, a diode has a roughly exponential current vs. voltage characteristic.  For most silicon small-signal diodes, operated normally, the forward diode drop is around 0.7V.  But note all the weasel-words: "most", "silicon", "small-signal", "normally".

If you took a typical small-signal diode (a 1N4148 is a nice old example) and hooked it up to a good stiff lab supply, then whatever you set the lab supply voltage to, that'll be the voltage of the diode -- no matter what the diode wants.

Now set the supply voltage to 0V, then you'd see no current.  At 0.25V a very sensitive meter could read a very small current.  At 0.5V the current would have increased by somewhere between 150 and 15000 times (the variance is because \$n\$ in the diode equation isn't well controlled -- although at room temperature \$V_T\$ is close enough to 26mV that analog circuit designers have it memorized).  At 0.7V, the diode's flowing some number of milliamps -- I'm going to guess between 1 and 100.

At 1V or so, you're just going to cook the diode.  Basically, you'll be putting enough current through it that it'll act like a diode (the actual junction) in series with a resistor (all the poor, soon-to-be-slag silicon around the junction).  If you do this briefly, you *may* still have a diode, but it probably won't meet spec.

If it's a glass-bodied diode, you may see it glowing.  This is because even though silicon is an indirect band-gap semiconductor, if you push it hard enough it *will* show LED action.  For a bit.  Until it dies.

If you give it 5V, you'll found that a good lab supply is an excellent machine for blowing up diodes.

Comment: So, a diode's voltage is always approximately its Q-point voltage and we can model it with a resistor in series even though the diode forward biased directly with the voltage source and the important thing here, is if we do that above the breakdown voltage it will burn out, am i right ?

Comment: Um - no, that's not what I said at all.  No, a diode's voltage isn't even necessarily close to any given voltage, so this "Q-point voltage" you're talking about means nothing in this context.  No, you cannot, in general, model it as a resistor in series (in series with what?), although there are *some special cases* where you can model it as a resistor in series with a voltage source.  And no, I said nothing at all about breakdown voltage -- that's a phenomenon of a *reverse-biased* diode, and everything I said applies to a *forward biased* diode.

Comment: But you didin't anaswer my question either, i'm confused. I wasn't asked about diode current, i asked about its voltage.

Comment: First, I gave you a current/voltage *relation*.  Solve it for voltage using high-school algebra, and you've got the answer in voltage.  Second, I've edited my answer.  Basically, "good stiff lab supply" means that it'll overwhelm whatever a 1N4148 wants, and impose that voltage on the diode.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage sources and diodes always have internal resistance  so the voltage drop always depends on this above saturation unless active current limited.

The power limits can burn it out at with a rise in temp of Rja= xx to xxx deg C/watt.

Supply Load regulation error is the ratio of source/load while diode resistance is inverse to its power rating +0/-50%.  Thus a 1W diode can can a bulk resistance of 0.5 ohm approx. to 1 ohm.

### Learning Electronics

- all parts are ideal and have 0 Ohms except resistors.

### Experts in Electronics

- all parts have resistance
- all insulators = dielectrics which have ESR and Rp=leakage uA at rated V

  - including batteries (Rs, ESR, CCA) and Voltage sources (% load regulation of Vmax/Imax)
  - including Voltage sources (Rs), diodes(Rs), transistors (Rce, Rbe), caps (ESR), Inductors (DCR)
- **Good news is KVL and KCL still applies**
- **but you must estimate/know** the Rs, DCR , ESR, Rce, CCA for the relevant part to compute/simulate when used below or beyond rated current or use an accurate parametric model with tolerances.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8iMZ5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**KVL and KCL will always work if your model is accurate.**

The experts use experience and read datasheets to linearized non-linear electronics and understand that Effective Series Resistance exists in  ALL components, it's just not always commonly shown  e.g. **Vce(sat)/Ic(sat)= Rce** . (just ignored if not significant)

Comment: I had to down vote this answer because it doesn't really address the OP's question but does have some superfluous information.

Comment: @Barry TY for your feedback.. Rather than that, this is the essence of KCL,  when the Voltages are subtracted.  So perhaps too brief but hardly superfluous. I hope you and TIM  realize the Shockley equation does not apply here beyond saturation!  (-2)

Comment: you need the Emission Coefficient, the Saturation current **and the bulk series resistance Rs** for each diode Right @TimWescott ?!  unlike your formula  so Rs which is the biggest variable in Si or Sch or LEDs within a family varies inverse with Pd

Comment: @Barry are you familar with cognitive bias effects of downvoting then ignoring my explanation